# how to handle null values for SQLDecimal datatype in FileHelper classes

Tags: c#, types, filehelpers

I am trying to load a file using FileHelpers (like it already except for this one issue :P )
I have to save CSV file data into the database, and so am using a SqlDecimal datatype to store the decimal values of the CSV files.

```
[FileHelpers.FieldOptional()]
[FileHelpers.FieldConverter(typeof(SqlDecimalConverter))]
public SqlDecimal Rate;
```

All this works fine, until I have a blank value for the FixRate1. This is flagged up with an error.

> "Warn Exception:Null Value found for
>   the field 'Rate' in the class
>   'SWTrade'. You must specify a
>   FieldNullValueAttribute because this
>   is a ValueType and can´t be null."

I tried putting [FileHelpers.FieldNullValue(SqlDecimal.Null)]  but it obviously throws an error.

> An attribute argument must be a
>   constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an
>   attribute parameter type

Even though I override the **FieldToString** method in the **SqlDecimalConverter** class, the function is not called, when reading the data.

Well, this being the case, is there a way I can assign any null value or even some other hardcoded value to the Rate data, which I can then replace with a null direclty in my own logic ?

Please do let me know if you would need more details.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The other comments are right u need to use

```
private decimal? internalRate;
```

And later create a property for the conversion, in fact the library only autoconverts native types and SqlDecimal is not one.

```
public SqlDecimal? Rate
{
    get 
    {
        if (internalRate.HasValue)
            return new SqlDecimal(internalRate.Value);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

PS: If u want to go to the custom converter way, to use it for read u need to override the method **StringToField** (**FieldToString** is called for writing)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Surprisingly, the FieldToString  function is not called and the file helper throws an exception directly.

Comment: U are returning a SqlDecimal value ?
Can u send me the code of the converter or paste it here to check whats wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a Nullable type.  If you are using a Nullable type then you don't need to specify the FieldNullValue attribute.

```
[FileHelpers.FieldConverter(typeof(SqlDecimalConverter))]
public SqlDecimal? Rate;
```

That approach works fine with DateTime using the FileHelpers built in type converter.

If that does not work then you could assign a default value that you could treat as a null.  But that can be problematic if there is an actual value that corresponds to the chosen default value:

```
[FieldNullValue(typeof(SqlDecimal), "-1")]
[FileHelpers.FieldConverter(typeof(SqlDecimalConverter))]
public SqlDecimal Rate;
```

**Update**

I just did a test and simply using a decimal? type works fine.  Then you can convert it in your code to the proper SqlType to access the database.  I think that is the easiest approach.

So the field would just look like:

```
public decimal? Rate;
```

no attributes required.

Comment: [FieldNullValue(typeof(SqlDecimal), "01/01/0001")]

Dont you think it would generate an error in itself when trying to convert a possible datetime value to a SQLDecimal type ?

Comment: Oops.  :)  Thanks -- that's a left over from a DateTime test.  Changed to -1.

Comment: {"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal'."}

is what I get when I put in the line mentioned by you.
[FieldNullValue(typeof(SqlDecimal), "-1")]

Any other ideas ???

Answer (score 2):

I've never worked with FileHelpers, but you could try instead:

```
[FileHelpers.FieldNullValue(null)]
public SqlDecimal? Rate;
```

In addition to your other attributes, of course.

Note the big change here - I added a question mark to `SqlDecimal` to make it a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

Then you can use `Rate.HasValue` to se whether it's null or not and `Rate.Value` to access the `SqlDecimal` if `HasValue` is true.

Something like this will properly use `SqlDecimal.Null` after you parse the file:

```
SqlDecimal trueRate = (Rate.HasValue ? Rate.Value : SqlDecimal.Null);
```

Edit - It's possible that if you make Rate nullable (`SqlDecimal?`) you don't even need the "FieldNullValue" attribute. Again, I'm not familiar with the library. :(

Comment: No, he mentioned he tried SqlDecimal.Null which is not a constant expression.

Comment: @Sapph: sorry, my bad - I didn't read the question (and your answer) carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `Decimal` or an appropriate .net datatype instead of `SqlDecimal`?
I am suggesting that you should change the code to `public Decimal? Rate;` instead.

Comment: Not quite sure how FileHelpers work. Will probably have to try and have a look at the source code. I actually want to convert the whole csv file into a datatable so I can SQLBulkCopy to persist the data.
But I get the following error, when using nullable types 

"DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>"

Also, upon calling "fileHelperEngine.ReadFileAsDT()"  the override method FieldToString() is not triggered.